# Should I add venting to my solid soffit, and how?

Tags: roof, ventilation

I am in the process of replacing some fascia boards on an eave that goes around one corner of my house.

I notice that the soffit is just a plain painted board with no deliberate venting. Although after 100 years gaps have opened up in the soffit's joints so there is accidental venting.

Before I install the new fascia boards I was planning to recondition the soffit and seal it, but I have heard that it is recommended that soffits be vented. If there is a plain board, what should I do? Drill holes in it?

Comment: Are all the soffits plain boards or are some vented?

Comment: Soffit vents are all but useless unless you have venting high in the system as well. Also, you can mess up existing venting by introducing new airflow paths. What's the current situation?

Comment: @isherwood The current situation is that none of the soffits of the house are vented. They are just solid boards. The house was built in 1910.

Comment: I asked about vents *high in the system*, as in ridge or gable vents.

Comment: @isherwood There are no other vents in the system.

Comment: "There are no other vents in the system" means there are no attic windows.  100 yr. old homes *all* were built with attic windows or gable vents...no deliberate exceptions.  What is being described is a 100 yr. old house with absolutely no means of venting the attic!

Comment: @JamesOlson The attic does have a window. I do not consider that a "Vent" since I keep that window closed most of the time.

Comment: Windows that can be opened are considered vents.  At one time, homeowners would use them as such when it got hot outside.  Windows at opposite ends of a gable would be opened to create a cross-current.  Soffit vents would be used if there was a window in only one end of a gable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately what I did was use a hole saw to make three holes of 1.5" in diameter in the soffit. In each hole I put two screens of stainless steel. One was kind of a cup-shaped screen that fit into the hole so that the bottom was flush with the outer face of the soffit. Then a second screen was stapled over the top of the hole on the inside of the soffit.

Answer (score 4):

Most roofs have intake and exhaust vents. Soffit vents can be used for intake, but they are not the only means of intake. If you have a vented roof and already have adequate intake venting, you don't need to add more.

Additionally, not all roofs need to be vented - there are "hot roof" designs where the rafter bays are insulated and sealed up. You wouldn't want to add intake venting to a system set up like that. Given that your house is 100 years old, you probably don't have one of those types of roofs, but it's possible that it was renovated at some point.

So, figure out what you have and go accordingly. If you do decide to vent, you should take a look at all the products out there and install according to what you like best. For example, there are round vents you can install by cutting a hole out with a hole saw and pushing the vent in place, ones where you cut out a rectangle, ones where you cut out a long strip down the length of the roof, etc.

There are also vents that install under or in place of fascia board, which might be good for your situation (in place of soffit venting), since you say you're removing the fascia anyway.

I would not just drill holes - soffit vents are cheap and have screens to keep animals & insects out.

[This PDF](http://www.cor-a-vent.com/pdf/balancedventilation.pdf) has a good explanation of how roof venting works. They're selling Cor-A-Vent products, but the explanations are good regardless. They do make a good under-fascia vent, but GAF, Owens-Corning, and other roofing suppliers do as well.

Here are some [GAF vents](http://www.gaf.com/roofing/residential/products/roof_vents/masterflow_soffit_undereave_vents) you can use for soffit venting. Others manufactures have similar products.

Comment: What about using a hole saw to make several large holes and then covering the holes with aluminum screen?

Comment: That's one option, but it's challenging to make it look finished.

Comment: note: the word "intake" implies "by mechanical means", as well as, unidirectional flow; when it comes to attic venting (roofs are not vented given they're already outside) the *airflow* tends to reverse seasonally.

Answer (score 0):

Drilling holes will certainly work, however there are vents made specifically for soffits -- called soffit vents, believe it or not -- and they're quite common and will look better than drilled holes.